# foursquare adding a tip exception

Tags: foursquare, http-status-code-400

I am working on foursquare API v2 in Android. 
In my application User can check-in and add a tip.

check- in method is working good but add a tip method got error.

```
private void methodTipAdd(String venueId, String tip, boolean auth) {

    StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/");
    urlBuilder.append("tips/add");
    urlBuilder.append('?');

    try{
        urlBuilder.append("venueId").append('=');
        urlBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(venueId, "UTF-8")).append('&');
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{   
        urlBuilder.append("text").append('=');
        urlBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(tip, "UTF-8")).append('&');
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    if (auth) {
        urlBuilder.append("oauth_token=");
        urlBuilder.append(getAccessToken());
    } else {
        urlBuilder.append("client_id=");
        urlBuilder.append(CLIENT_ID);
        urlBuilder.append("&client_secret=");
        urlBuilder.append(CLIENT_SECRET);
    }

    urlBuilder.append("&v=" + getVersion());


    String url = urlBuilder.toString();


    String result = null;

    try {
        URL aUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) aUrl.openConnection();
        try {
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.connect();

            int code = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (code == 200) {
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                result = convertStreamToString(inputStream);
                android.util.Log.e(tag, "result: " + result);
                // handle tip 
            } else {
                android.util.Log.e(tag, "HttpURLConnection response code: " + code);
            }

        } finally {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

request url : https://api.foursquare.com/v2/tips/add?venueId=[venue id]&text=[utf-8 encoded text]&oauth_token=[my_oauth_token]&v=20120730 
ex) https://api.foursquare.com/v2/tips/add?venueId=XXX123YYY&text=Good&oauth_token=XXX123YYY&v=20120730

http response code: 400

I want to know why i got the HTTP_BAD_REQUEST response code.

Answer (score 1):

when doing a POST the parameters should not be part of the URL (specify them as parameters to the POST).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

```
private void methodTipAdd3(String venueId, String tip) {
    String url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/tips/add";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("oauth_token=");
    sb.append(getAccessToken()).append('&');

    try{
        sb.append("venueId").append('=');
        sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(venueId, "UTF-8")).append('&');
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{   
        sb.append("text").append('=');
        sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(tip, "UTF-8")).append('&');
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    sb.append("v=" + getVersion());

    String params = sb.toString();

    String result = null;

    int httpcode = 200;

    try {
        URL aUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) aUrl.openConnection();
        try {

            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            byte buf[] = params.getBytes("UTF-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(buf.length));
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream outputstream = connection.getOutputStream();
            outputstream.write(buf);
            outputstream.flush();
            outputstream.close();

            httpcode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (httpcode == 200) {
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                result = convertStreamToString(inputStream);
                // handle tip 
                android.util.Log.e(tag, "result: " + result);
            } else {
                android.util.Log.e(tag, "http response code: " + httpcode);
            }

        } finally {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```